# Change font via `ERT` at LyX

Tags: fonts, lyx, font-encodings

I want to change font at LyX via `ERT` (e.g. for one of the Culmus Hebrew fonts).
I remeber that was one command like `\set...{fontname}` and then the font change to *fontname* (What was before this command was with no change...

Can you help me and tell me which command is it?

**And not via XeTex/LuaTex**....

Thank you!

Comment: The commands you seem to have in mind are from `fontspec` but you need to use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX to make use of those. In that case you could do something like `\newfontfamily{\fontcommand}{font name}` and then `\fontcommand` or `\setmainfont{font name}`, `\setsansfont{font name}` and `\setmonofont{font name}`, switching between the families as you wish. The use of a script such as that in which Hebrew is written will be a whole lot easier with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX. Is there some particular reason you prefer a more difficult solution?

Comment: @cfr, I'm sure that it was just one command and it worked....

Comment: Well, `\setmainfont{font name}` is just one command and will change the current main font. But the command is from `fontspec` so you need to use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr, It doesn't work for me...

Comment: @cfr, I'm remembering that there was a very short way...

Comment: `http://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/` offers support for the use of the Cumulus fonts with regular LaTeX on Linux. Support is also available from MiKTeX on Windows. See http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html. It is impossible to say why it doesn't work without seeing your code. Probably the font name is not specified as xelatex expects, for example, but you probably also need something like `babel` or, probably better, `polyglossia`.